# Jquery dialogue gives the text undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is how my jquery dialogue looks like. The dialogue has "undefined" written rather than "ok". Another plugin on the same site gives the correct dialogue with button text as "ok". I am using jquery ui 1.8

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post your code and/or an example on a site like jsfiddle.net.

Comment: This could simply be a typo in the parameter names. But without code...

Comment: you have 2 different dialog plugins? maybe there is a conflict. please include your code!

Comment: I had a plugin that used the dialogue as  <div id="success-message"><p>Done!</p></div>  and created an overlay dialogue. So i used another div at another location with same id of the div to give the same effect. But in the second place i get an error. This might be due to 2 divs having the same id?

Comment: Never never give the same ID to two elements. That's illegal and many functions/plugin rely on the fact that there is only one element mapped to an id.